# .Net application on Azure Virtual Sever trying to connect to Azure database service

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a .net application that connects to a SQL database using the Azure database service. it is working on my local PC. But after deploying the application on Azure Virtual Machine, it times out when trying to connect to Azure database service. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are opening the correct Network Security Group ports needed to connect to the database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview